# how to translate struct packing from vc++ to gcc

Tags: c++

How to translate the below vc++ packing commands into gcc commands in Linux? I am aware how to do it for a single struct, but how do I do this for a range of struct?

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // exact fit - no padding
//structures here
#pragma pack(pop) //back to whatever the previous packing mode was
```

Comment: Since gcc supports the pragma pack compiler commands, we can stick with the above code.

Comment: See this too... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537964/visual-c-equivalent-of-gccs-attribute-packed?rq=1)

Comment: thx Neon, I will test my program again carefully

Comment: Common compilers will be happy with `pragma pack` including borland, digital mars, gcc. So you can keep this unless you are planning to use some less common compilers. _Target platform also matters. Hope you are on x86. Otherwise you may need more reference._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add **attribute**((packed)) to individual data items to achieve this. In this case the packing is applied for a data item, so no need to restore the old mode.

Ex :
For Structures :

```
typedef struct _MY_STRUCT
{

}__attribute__((packed)) MY_STRUCT;
```

For data members :

```
struct MyStruct {

    char c;

    int myInt1 __attribute__ ((packed));

    char b;

    int myInt2 __attribute__ ((packed));

};
```

Answer (score 1):

gcc also supports those pragmas. See the compiler docs at:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

alternatively you could use the more gcc-specific

```
__attribute__(packed)
```

example:

```
struct foo {
  int16_t one;
  int32_t two;
} __attribute__(packed);
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

Comment: Yes. I am actually aware how to do it for a single struct. How do I do this for a range of struct?

Comment: Since gcc suports the pragma pack compiler commands why not do it the same way?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html, gcc should support `#pragma pack` directly, so you can use it directly as is.

The `gcc way` of specifying alignment is `__attribute__((aligned(x)))`, where `x` is required alignment.

You can also use `__attribute__((packed))` to specify tightly packed struct.

Refer to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html