# What are the differences between #pragma pack(push, n)/#pragma pack(pop) and __attribute__((__packed__, aligned(n) )) on GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, memory-alignment

On GCC specifically (that is, compiling both with GCC), what are the differences between the way the following two work?

```
struct foo1 {
    char a;
    int b;
} __attribute__((__packed__, aligned(n) ));
```

and:

```
#pragma pack(push, n)
struct foo2 {
    char a;
    int b;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

They [appear to behave differently](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b134364f7e775f87):

```
foo1 f1;
foo2 f2;

int& i1 = f1.b; // ok
int& i2 = f2.b; // cannot bind packed field 'f2.foo2::b' to 'int&'
```

Why is there an error in one yet not the other? Are the memory layouts the same, at least?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't say which version of GCC you're using, but you can find the appropriate manual [on-line](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).  They're all pretty compatible in these regards, however, inasmuch as the behavior of attributes and pragmas, once defined, is normally maintained across versions for compatibility.  I'll draw specific quotations from the manual for GCC 4.9.3, currently the latest available version from the GCC 4 series.  In particular, the sections on [type attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes) and on [structure-packing pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html#Structure-Packing-Pragmas) are relevant.

The GCC manual says of `#pragma pack` and friends:

> #pragma directives that change the *maximum* alignment of *members* of structures (other than zero-width bit-fields), unions, and classes subsequently defined.

(emphasis added).  It says of `__attribute__((packed))`:

> This attribute, attached to struct or union type definition, specifies that each member (other than zero-width bit-fields) of the structure or union is placed to minimize the memory required.

It says of `__attribute__ ((aligned(n)))`:

> This attribute specifies a *minimum* alignment for *variables of the specified type*, measured in bytes.

(emphasis added).

Thus, no, `#pragma pack(n)`, with or without `push`, does not, in general, mean the same as attaching `__attribute__((packed, aligned(n))` to the structure type.  The former specifies that members of affected structures be aligned on `n`-byte or finer boundaries.  The latter specifies that members of the affected structure be packed with the minimum permissible padding, and that the chosen alignment requirement for instances of the overall structure must be no less than `n`.  Not only are those not the same, they're not even very similar.

You should find that `#pragma pack(1)` affecting a structure definition has the same effect on the layout of instances as does attaching `__attribute__((packed))` to that structure's definition.  Even if they accomplish the same end, however, they are not the *same thing*.  The behavior and effects of both are outside the C++ specification, and GCC is entirely within its rights to treat them differently in other respects.

If you want to use attributes to influence the alignment of structure members, however, then you will need to apply at least some attributes on a member-by-member basis.  For example ...

```
struct foo1 {
    char a;
    int b __attribute__((aligned(n)));
} __attribute__((packed));
```

... might have the same effect as ...

```
#pragma pack(push, n)
struct foo2 {
    char a;
    int b;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

..., depending on `n`.

Comment: *"You should find that #pragma pack(1) has the same effect on a struct definition as does attaching __attribute__((packed)) to that definition"* : however, one compiles, the other does not in the example posted by the OP.

Comment: @m.s. they both compile fine for me with g++ 4.4.7.  Then again, so does his original example.  I have nevertheless revised my answer to narrow and sharpen it a bit in that area.

Comment: indeed, [g++ 4.4.7 (and a few more old versions) compiles this code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/evDwNE8RgMwxO9HB), while [g++ 4.7.3 (and later) does not](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zQZWjWa4T2CbLkgD)