# Why does scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve crash when numpy.linalg.solve does not?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a sparse Matrix `B` and an array `b` (uploaded [here](https://file.io/QOrK3j5inVW8)), and am trying to do

```
import numpy as np
import config
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
from scipy.sparse import load_npz
from numpy.linalg import solve

B = load_npz('B.npz')
b = np.load('b.npy')

spsolve(B, b)
```

which leads to

```
corrupted size vs. prev_size
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)
```

the same problem does not happen when I use numpy.linalg.solve:

```
B_dense = np.array(B.todense())
solve(B_dense, b)
Out[5]: 
array([-299.77073372, -299.68350884, -299.59972996, ..., -286.52926438,
   -286.50847706, -286.48927409])
```

So since numpy's version works, I suppose nothing is "wrong" with my matrices? Why does this occur? And since this crashes the code without a trace -- is there perhaps a way to "wrap" the error in an exception, to run solve whenever spsolve would lead to an issue?

Comment: That sounds like a problem that should be reported to [SciPy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues).  Be sure to include which versions of SciPy and NumPy you are using, and which platform this is on (i.e. is it Linux, Windows, Mac or something else).

Comment: "And since this crashes the code without a trace -- is there perhaps a way to "wrap" the error in an exception, to run solve whenever spsolve would lead to an issue?" No - this is some kind of memory safety error which corrupts the memory used by the memory allocator. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49660707/530160). Once this corruption has occurred, there is no way to uncorrupt it, except by terminating the entire process.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu 22.04. I'm guessing this is a version-dependent and OS-dependent issue.

Comment: @NickODell I think the first comment sufficiently answers my question if you frame it as such, thanks