# Porting issue Linux/Unix build to Windows — Visual C++ can't find the attribute keyword?

Tags: c, windows, attributes, porting

I think my new Windows machine cannot find the "attribute" mechanism. Is this because `__attribute__` is a GNU thing only? I am trying to compile some headers that I created on my Linux box using gcc. I am using Visual C++ 6.0 for the first time in my life. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
typedef struct s_mystruct {
         unit somevar;
} __attribute__((packed)) MyStruct;
```

Error :
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '**attribute**'
error C2061: "syntax error : identifier '**attribute**' "

Same type of error at different place -->

```
**typedef unsigned long uint128_t __attribute__ ((mode(TI)));
                typedef long int128_t __attribute__ ((mode(TI)));**
```

This time even code is not enabled :(

Well, we can of course implement -

```
#define __attribute__(x)
```

which will simply remove the remark from the code during pre-processing.

But this solution may change build behavior.

Please suggest a better solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1545341/13912132 for __attribute__((packed))

Comment: For mode(TI), I think, there is no equivalent

Comment: The `__attribute__` notation is a GCC extensiion, not standard C.  If you're not using GCC, it won't necessarily work.  As it happens, Clang also accepts the notation; for the most part, it is compatible with GCC.  But Visual C++ is not GCC compatible.  And Visual C++ 6.0 is archaic, isn't it?  Wikipedia says [Visual C++ 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History) was released in 1998.  You should not be using it without an extraordinarily good reason.

Comment: If you're porting to Windows it's easier to stick with GCC by using MinGW-w64. A standalone compiler can be downloaded from: http://winlibs.com/