# Visual Studio Code complaining about struct attribute syntax

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, arm

In the following code snippet (C, for ARM embedded chips)

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) MyStruct_S
{
    int MyFirstField;
    int MySecondField;
} MyStruct_Type;
```

VS Code complains on the MyStruct_S identifier, following the attribute. The complaint says "expected a ';'C/C++(65)".

And yet this code compiles and runs just fine even with -Wall and -Wextra compiler flags set.

**What is VS Code doing wrong?** Can we fix the IntelliSence to see that this is correct syntax?

The extensions I have for this workspace are the following:

- Arm Assembly
- C/C++
- Doxygen Documentation Generator
- GNU Linker Map files
- Makefile Tools
- WSL

cheers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537964/visual-c-equivalent-of-gccs-attribute-packed

Comment: @abelenky OP is not using Visual C++.

Comment: @abelenky How is your comment related to my question?

Comment: Given the structure definition, `__attribute__((__packed__))` seems useless.

Comment: @chqrlie you're right, this is an example... did you think I had a structure called MyStruct_Type with a field called MyFirstField in a real project?

Comment: @GregoryFenn VS Code is just the IDE. The message is given by the compiler. Which compiler suite are you using?

Comment: @Serkan it is mentioned "And yet this code compiles and runs just fine even with -Wall and -Wextra compiler flags set." Therefore that message seems to come from Intellisense, not from the compiler.

Comment: @Serkan - the compiler is arm-none-eabi-gcc v8.3.1. As I said in my question, the compilation and execution run just fine. So the compiler is not the problem, the IDE is the issue.

Comment: @GregoryFenn: my comment was meant as a joke :)  The problem seems to be a configuration issue: VS Code uses a language server that does not support the gcc extension `__attribute__`.  You might want to add `#ifdef _MSC_VER    #define __attribute__(x)     #endif`

Comment: The Intellisense engine is assuming MSVC extensions, where gcc extension `__attribute__((__packed__))` makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the C/C++ Extension Configurations. Select a suitable one under the `Intellisense Mode`. On Windows, it is by default set to windows-msvc-x64, and on Linux, linux-gcc-x64. Create a new C/C++ configuration (`C/C++: Edit Configurations` command), and set the Intellisense Mode to `linux-gcc-arm`. Then for your project, using the `"C/C++: Select a configuration..."` command change your configuration.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! (New to VS Code, the User/Workspace settings for my multiple folders got me a bit confused :) )